# The operation couldn't be completed. (Starscream.WSError error 1.) RBSManager

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, websocket, ros

I am trying to connect to ROS Machine using iOS App I am using the **RBSManager**

> it's A Swift-native library for handling the WebSocket connection to a
>   Robot Operating System (ROS) master running ROSBridge for Controll
>   your robots with a mobile phone

.

but everytime I am trying to connect to ROS machine I got an Errore:

```
The operation couldn't be completed. (Starscream.WSError error 1.)
```

I am using swift 4 as a programming language and xcode 10 as IDE.

and the host that I am trying to connect to is: "192.168.69.155:11311".

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same problem. I can see on the ROS Bridge server (running in Ubuntu with Turtlesim) side that a connection is made and then it gets disconnected immediately.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably two things that you need to fix to get this working presently.

1) use port 9090 which is the default instead of 11311 assuming you haven't changed it specifically. In the host text input of the RBSManager example app, type `ws://192.168.69.155:9090` (the `ws://` can be omitted if you prefer). Port 11311 is the default port and would be the port to use if this was a ROS < > ROS connection (e.g. two Ubuntu machines on the same subnet running ROS). ROS Bridge provides a different function which is similar, except that the data is transmitted in JSON format.

2) If you're getting the error when trying to get RBSManager to work with ROS Kinetic (on Ubuntu 16.04), then it seems there is a problem with one of the libraries, `tornado` on the ROS Kinetic side. Try downgrading from version 5.1.1 to 4.5.3. Doing this fixed the issue for me. This solution came from [After tornado upgraded to version 5.0, websocket disconnects immediately after connection #353](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/issues/353#issuecomment-416934333)

Here are the commands:
`pip uninstall tornado`,
`pip install tornado==4.5.3`

Lastly, the same RBSManager example app will work without any tweaks to tornado with ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04.